# How does $e^{-i\vec a \cdot \vec p}$ translate a quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, symmetry, unitarity

I'm reading Conceptual Framework of QFT by Anthony Duncan, and at the bottom of page 77 he says

> The translation of a physical system by displacement $\vec a$ is of course effected by the unitary operator
> $$U_{trans}(\vec a) = e^{-i\vec a \cdot \vec p}$$
> where $\vec p$ is the total 3-momentum vector for the system.

I guess this is supposed to be obvious but I don't get it.  It must be specific to a quantum system if it's a complex operator.  But then how are we even justified in talking about the "total 3-momentum", since there will in general be a superposition of momentum eigenstates?  And how does this operator induce a translation of the state by $\vec a$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
e^{-i \vec a \cdot \vec{\hat p}} = e^{-i \vec a \cdot -i \vec \nabla} = e^{-\vec a \cdot \vec \nabla}\\
\text{so that }\qquad e^{-i \vec a \cdot \vec{\hat p}} \psi(\vec x) = \psi(\vec x-\vec a)
$$
by Taylor's expansion theorem. Thus this would work even if it is not in a momentum eigenstate.

Enjoy the great book~

Answer (score 0):

Another way to derive is the following : add a dimensionless parameter $u\in[0,1]$ and set :
$$O(u) = e^{iu \vec a \cdot \vec p}$$

This is a solution to the (operator valued) ODE :
$$\frac{\text d}{\text du}O(u) = i\vec a \cdot \vec p \mathcal O(u)\tag{$*$}$$
If we find another solution of this equation with the same initial condition $\mathcal O(u) = 1$, the two operators must be equal. So we now want to show that the translation operator $T(u\vec a)$ is also a solution.

We can show that this is the case when we multiply on the right by an arbitrary stat $|\psi_0\rangle$. Let $|\psi(u)\rangle = T(u\vec a )|\psi_0\rangle$. In position space, we have :
$$\psi(u,\vec x) = \psi_0(\vec x  +u\vec a)$$
Therefore:
\begin{align}
\partial_u \psi(u,\vec x) &= \vec a \cdot \vec \partial_x \psi_0(\vec x  +u\vec a) \\
&= \vec a\cdot \vec \partial_x \psi(u,\vec x)
\end{align}

Written differently, this is :
$$\frac{\text d}{\text du}|\psi(u)\rangle = i\vec a\cdot\vec p|\psi(u)\rangle$$
which implies that $T(u\vec a)$ is a solution of $(*)$. At $u=1$ we get :
$$T(\vec a) = e^{i\vec a\cdot\vec p}$$